# How can I play and stop an animation based on an an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, animation

I'd like to be able to create an animation that can be played and stopped (reset).

Here is what I have so far:

```
function animateObject(amountArray) {
  // Sample data
  amountArray = ["0", "1", "3", "2", "0"];
  duration = 500;

  // Looping through each value and animating the object 
  for(i=0; i<amountArray.length; i++) {

    $('#object').animate({
      top: amountArray[i]
    },duration);

  } // endloop

}
```

This accurately animates the object but calling `$('#object').stop();` anywhere doesn't seem to stop the animation.

I presume that is because the loop is already built out and nothing can stop it after it's executed.

Comment: Where is the "placement" var defined? Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Ah! I cleared that up in an edit. The `top` value is defined by the current `amountArray` value while looping. The point isn't so much that these values derive from an array but that these values need to be looped through and used to animate with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `.stop(true)`.  That should clear queued animations.

Comment: Yup! Thanks, that works. I guess it builds an internal queue of animations and that does stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use setInterval to controle the start and stop?

http://jsfiddle.net/YdZrZ/12/